# Use powershell/Azure automation to turn on SSRS and update IP for email

Tags: powershell, azure, reporting-services

I just got a handle on Azure Automation and now have my VM on a scheduled off/on. This is great and will help get my VM costs under control, unfortunately I still have to manually login to the VM and turn on SSRS and update the email IP for the service. 
Is there a way to turn on SSRS and update the email IP in SSRS from powershell? To temper responses, I have little experience working with powershell and C.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need anything clarified.

-Rob

Comment: Are you running the SSRS Instance in Sharepoint Integrated or Native Mode?

Answer (score 0):

To start SSRS with powershell you would normally start the service as with `start-service ReportServer` for example. To change the configuration you might access the SSRS Webservice or change the configuration xml file directly, which you can find under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config`. You can find the documentation for the config file [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273(v=sql.105).aspx)...